# Calculating STREEBOG256 and STREEBOG512 hashes using c++ and openssl

Tags: c++, hash, openssl

I'm trying to leverage `openssl` to calculate `STREEBOG256` and `STREEBOG512` hashes in `c++`.

I can do this for MD5, SHA*, RIPEMD160, etc with no problems.  Openssl can definitely do it via the command line interface (see below) but I can't figure out how to add support to my c++ program.  Using MD5 as an example, it can be achieved by including the `openssl/md5.h` header, making calls to `MD5_Init`, `MD5_Update`, `MD5_Final`, and by linking to `libcrypto`.

Although openssl lists `STREEBOG256` and `STREEBOG512` as supported hash algorithms in the command line application, I can't find any references in the source to these.  There's no mention of STREEBOG in any of the tests that I can see.

A little research shows that STREEBOG is defined in standard GOST R 34.11-2012. 
I thought perhaps it was referred to by it's standard name within the source. I see references to 34.11-94 but none to 2012 so that was a dead-end.

I'm clearly missing something obvious here.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
>openssl dgst -streebog256 <myfile> 
streebog256(<myfile>)= 62c091360b1c75abcf2a4230146b1d0e752c12c89543c22ee2773b60e54fd447

>openssl dgst -streebog512 <myfile> 
streebog512(<myfile>)= af6e5261de459192028db6595299742a2f19b9ee84c821661861ad89d82a907b195aff841f2d81f91576e62c3741c59362ec2633b10c4732267f61ed5aacc7b3
```

Comment: It might help adding the output of `openssl version` and details about the system it is running on to the question. On my system (ubuntu bionic) the `openssl dgst -streebog256 <myfile>` does not work, but per google there are some man pages containing that option out there.

Comment: Thank you @user10605163.  You're absolutely right.  I'm on MacOS and the `openssl` running natively is `LibreSSL 2.6.4` and not `OpenSSL 1.0.2q` as I had assumed.  Sure enough, `streebog` is part of libressl and not openssl.  Libressl is a fork of openssl.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per discussion in the comments the `-streebogXXX` options are provided by LibreSSL, but not OpenSSL.

The `openssl` command is actually provided by LibreSSL instead of OpenSSL on systems using the LibreSSL fork of OpenSSL.

To find the implementation of the hash function, one should therefore look in the sources of LibreSSL.

Answer (score 0):

With OpenSSL you need to init the gost engine:

```
$ openssl dgst -engine gost -md_gost12_256 test.txt
```

With LibreSSL:

```
$ libressl dgst -streebog256 test.txt
```